# How can I create a directive that contains other directives?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created some new directives like this:

```
<admin-retrieve-button></admin-retrieve-button>
<admin-new-button></admin-new-button>
<admin-save-button></admin-save-button>
<admin-reset-button></admin-reset-button>
```

Is there a way I can create another directive that combines all of these?

Answer (score 1):

you can use ng-transclude for that

```
app.directive("adminButtonGroup", function(){
   return {
     restrict: 'E'
     transclude: true,
      template: '<div class="btn-group"><div ng-transclude=""></div></div>'
    }
 });
```

OR if you do not want to transclude and have fixed set of buttons then

```
  app.directive("adminButtonGroup", function(){
   return {
     restrict: 'E';
      template: '<admin-retrieve-button></admin-retrieve-button>' +
                  '<admin-new-button></admin-new-button>' +
                  '<admin-save-button></admin-save-button>' +
                  '<admin-reset-button></admin-reset-button';
    }
 });
```

also you can use require, if your child button wants to speak with parent button.

Comment: Can you explain more about require? I don't know anything about this.

Comment: read [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives-part-two/) `The Controller and require`

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Create a template that contains theses tags, which is then used in your new directive by setting the templateUrl property to the path to the template file.